# using jQuery to show associated items from a model in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I'm trying to dynamically display a column of items associated with a selected item in another column. See picture at bottom. So explicitly, if you click on the program "Fat Loss," the Cycles that are in the Fat Loss Program will be displayed.

Tt's as simple as replacing the 3 in `Program.find(3).cycles.each` with the id of whatever program is clicked, but after a few hours, I can't figure out how to dynamically replace code within a code block. Any help in the right direction is really appreciated!

This is the html for the page in the screenshot:

```
<h2>Program</h2>
              <ul class="sortable" data-update-url="<%= sort_programs_url %>">
                <% @programs.each do |program| %>
                  <%= content_tag_for :li, program, class: "card" do %>
                    <%= link_to program.name, program %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
              <%= link_to 'Add New Program', new_program_path, :class => 'add-new' %>
              <!-- Column one end -->
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
              <!-- Column two start -->
              <h2>Cycle</h2>
              <ul class="sortable">
                <% Program.find(3).cycles.each do |cycle| %>
                <li class="card" id="cycle-<%= cycle.id %>">
                  <%= truncate(cycle.name, :length => 20, :separator => ' ') %>
                </li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
              <%= link_to 'Add New Cycle', new_cycle_path, :class => 'add-new' %>
              <!-- Column two end -->
            </div>
```

And the Models:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cycles_programs
  has_many :cycles, :through => :cycles_programs

class Cycle < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cycles_programs
  has_many :programs, :through => :cycles_programs
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should go with ajax here and move the `<ul class="sortable">` block to a partial.  On click of one of the programs you will call an action in your controller which will set the selected program and replace the `ul` block with rendered partial from your `action.js.erb`.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you're saying. I'll give that a try and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct way to do this in Rails is by moving the parts of code I want to have appear and disappear into partials, and using JS to make those partials appear and disappear. The best tutorial I could find for how to do this type of thing is Ryan Bates rails tutorial on [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised).

In the RailsCast, once you get into the section on how to make form fields appear and be removed, you'll get a pretty good idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the interface logic into JavaScript. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { width: 300px; float: left; margin-right: 20px; }
        li { list-style: none; border: 1px solid #555; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px; margin: 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="program">
    <h2>Program</h2>
    <ul id="programs">
    </ul>
    <a href="#add_program">Add Program</a>
</div>
<div class="cycle">
    <h2>Cycle</h2>
    <ul id="cycles">
    </ul>
    <a href="#add_cycle">Add Cycle</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //  Source data via ajax? constructed as part of building page?
    var data = [
        {name:'Fat Loss', cycles: ['Cycle 1', 'Cycle 2']},
        {name:'Licks balls', cycles: ['Cycle 3', 'Cycle 4']},
        {name:'klasdjfa', cycles: ['ReCycle', 'Deep Cycle', 'UniCycle']},
        {name:'Testing Programs', cycles: ['Scotch', 'Soda']},
        {name:'Hypertrophy', cycles: ['Clockwise', 'CounterClockwise', 'Sidewise']}
    ];
    //  display set of cycles   
    var display_cycles = function(cycle_list) {
        var cycles = document.getElementById('cycles');
        var cycle;
        cycles.innerHTML = '';

        for ( var k in cycle_list ) {
            cycle = document.createElement('li');
            cycle.innerHTML = cycle_list[k];
            cycles.appendChild(cycle);
        }
    };

    var programs = document.getElementById('programs');
    var program, trigger;

    // initial programs display
    for ( var j in data ) {
        program = document.createElement('li');
        trigger = document.createElement('a');
        trigger.setAttribute('href', '#'+j);
        trigger.setAttribute('class', 'trigger_cycles');
        trigger.setAttribute('onclick', 'display_cycles(data['+j+']["cycles"])');
        trigger.innerHTML = data[j]['name'];
        program.appendChild(trigger);
        programs.appendChild(program);
    }

    //  Cycles for the first program
    display_cycles(data[0]['cycles']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```